# Using `emacsclient` as `git config core.editor` and invoking `git commit` as `shell-command` in Emacs?

Tags: git, shell-command

I am trying to use Emacs 25.1.1 (graphical version, Windows 10) as both the primary editor and the editor for git operations.

In my workflow, I invoke git through `M-x shell-command`.

I tried the following two options so far:

1. `git config --global core.editor "emacs -Q"`

   With this, `M-x shell-command RET git commit` works just fine, as a new light-weight instance of emacs is used.

   Downside: Completion with `M-/` aka `dabbrev-expand` is less useful than it could be.
2. `git config --global core.editor "emacsclient --no-wait --create-frame"`

   With this setting, trying to execute git synchrnously as 
   `M-x shell-command RET git commit`
   on the other hand causes the `emacsclient` and server `emacs` processes to hang indefinitely, until `emacsclient is killed, while the asynchrnous invocation 
   `M-x shell-command RET git commit &`
   works, but this setup is too brittle, as forgetting the & causes Emacs to all but crash.

Is there some way to use `emacsclient` as git editor, that is compatible with `M-x shell-command`?

Comment: As a workaround (not answering your question), you could consider using magit (which is amazing) or the `vc-*` commands that are built-in (e.g. `C-x v v`). As another workaround, you could use `M-x async-shell-command`.

Comment: @aplaice The first workaround seems viable, though I can't seem to figure out an equivalent of ``git commit -a`` or `git commit file1 file2`. Due to such issues I prefer working directly with the shell commands over learning multiple interfaces for the same action. The second workaround is equivalent to the use got ``shell-command`` with leading ``&`` and suffers from the same problems; Most of the time the synchronous version is preferable for me, so its likely I'll end up crashing emacs by forgetting to use the asynchrnous version. The downsides of using `runemacs -Q` are smaller than that.

Comment: Little correction: It should be ``emacs -Q`` not ``runemacs -Q`` as  I had originally written. With ``runemacs -Q`` the editor is detached from git, making git think it was closed with an empty commit message.

Comment: I think you want https://github.com/magit/with-editor

Answer (score 1):

If you run git within a posix environment (cygwin or msys, I believe git-bash uses msys), you could create a function in your ~/.profile:

```
function already_emacsing () {
   emacsclient --eval '(find-file-other-window $1)'
}
EDITOR="already_emacsing"
```

I can't test it on your setup right now, but the individual parts all work and I can't see any reason they shouldn't fit together well enough. I can't think of a way to do the same with batch scripting, but it's probable you could do the same emacsclient call with a powershell script or something as well.

Comment: I am running git from within the Windows version of Emacs, so it is executed through ``cmdproxy.exe``, not through a posix shell, and thus this solution isn't applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Does Emacs 25.1.1 not have [`async-shell-command`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Single-Shell.html)?

Per the docstring,

> Like ‘shell-command’, but adds ‘&’ at the end of COMMAND to execute it
> asynchronously.

It is bound to `M-&` by default.